# Cannot authenticate into google datastore through REST Api

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I tried to access Google's Datastore through their REST Api. It says that they allow authentication through the API-key. However it doesn't seems that I can get it to work any where. I copied the snippet generated from their `Try this API` page.

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID:runQuery?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"query":{"filter":{"compositeFilter":{"op":"AND","filters":[{"propertyFilter":{"property":{"name":"id"},"op":"EQUAL","value":{"stringValue":"ID"}}}]}},"kind":[{"name":"NAME"}]},"partitionId":{"namespaceId":"NAMESPACE_ID","projectId":"PROJECT_ID"}}' \
  --compressed
```

But it keeps returning me an 401 error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

It looks like it require me to use OAuth instead, which is not what their documentation says. Anyone experienced something similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using an API key which is incorrect.

This link details which services support API Keys. Cloud Datastore is not one of them.

[Using API Keys](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys)

You want to use an Access Token which is derived from Service Account credentials.

Review this document.

[Using OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests)

The steps to generate an Access Token:

1. Load the service account credentials json file.
2. Extract the `client_email`, `private_key` and `private_key_id`.
3. Create a json payload.
4. Call the authorization URL: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
5. This returns a json object. Extract the `access_token`.
6. Use the `access_token` instead of an API Key.

There are examples on the Internet in various languages. The link will get you started. The process appears complicated, and it is, but once you understand it, generating Access Tokens is easy and they can be reused until they expire (typically 60 minutes which you control).

This document on Google Cloud Storage authentication is the same for Cloud Datastore. The key is understanding "Authorization: Bearer" which is a header you need to include with your curl request.

[Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication)

Comment: This is the way I intrepret [Using API Keys] (https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) 's first bullet point, `A limited number of GCP services allow access using only an API key`. Those services can only be authenticated through API key, the rest can be authenticate through both API key or other auth mechanism. Is that interpretation incorrect? Should it just be, only those services can be authenticated with only an API key, the rest require more than an API key?

Comment: As you saw from the error message an Access Token is expected (required). Go to the Google Cloud Console -> APIs and Services -> Credentials. Click the "Create credentials" button. Select "Help me choose". Walk thru the wizard and it will tell you that you need Service Account credentials for Cloud Datastore.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much @John Hanley